# html 5 postmessage in opera 11.x

Tags: html, opera, postmessage

i use such construction in iframe to send its height to parent window:

```
<body onload="parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, '*');">
    ...
</body>
```

there is a listener in parent window:

```
function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id)
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event)
    {
        if (isNaN(event.data)) return;
        var height = parseInt(event.data);
        iframe.height = height + "px";
    }, false);
}

<iframe id="voice-iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('voice-iframe');" src="http://localhost:2040/VoiceApi/Base">
</iframe>
```

this code works in ff, chrome, safari, ie9, probably in ie8, but not in opera 11 (though no errors are shown in dragonfly).
i thought there will be some problems with ie but not with the last version of opera.
or maybe i'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: the problem was that postmessage in opera is document's method, not window's.

Comment: That's not correct (anymore) - the initial implementation was on document but it's changed to be window.postMessage() long ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think onload fires *inside* the IFRAME first, postMessage() will then cause a message event to happen, and then finally the onload *attribute* on the IFRAME will trigger. If you add the event listener from the IFRAME tag's onload handler, you'll probably *start* listen for the message after it was sent, so you won't receive anything.

Comment: i understand that, but everything worked in ff, chrome and ie, so i thought that this message is put into a queue somehow and is processed later by parent window, but in opera it is lost.

Comment: If you rely on a particular timing of cross-frame event handling, you're pretty much asking for race conditions and hard-to-debug problems across different browsers, network conditions etc. Try to avoid race conditions and timing-sensitive code in JavaScript, and you'll have fewer grey hairs eventually :)

Comment: (That said, Opera *should* try to align its event processing order for this case with what other browsers do, and I'll report a bug for it. Timing issues in JavaScript are poorly understood by most developers and hence an interesting topic to be aware of.)

Comment: curiously, I tried writing a test case to demonstrate the order of events you're seeing, but I get all browsers behaving exactly like Opera. Could you share a link to a page where you see this problem? (It's fine if you've applied workarounds - just tell me how to undo them ;))